# How can I have a method in an Object return an object with a dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app I'm trying to create a wrapper for the Google Maps service. In order to set the parameters of the map I have to create an object with all the parameters. I'm trying to do this in the mapOptions property. Ideally I'd like to have small helper methods inside the object compute the values for the Google Maps options Object, however I'm getting an "Undefined is not a function" error when I try to set the center property of the object I'm creating to objects in my MapBackgroundGenerator object. I'm assuming its a scope issue, but I'm not sure how to access my helper methods inside my object creation method.

```
App.MapBackgroundGenerator = Ember.Object.extend
  placesService: null 
  placeId: null
  mapContainer: null
  setMapLocationFrom: (placeId) ->
    console.log(placeId)
    @get('placesService').getDetails(placeId: placeId, (place, status) =>
      console.log(place)
      # @set('placeLocation', place.geometry.location)
      return place.geometry.location
    )

  placeLocation: 1111

  # ).observes('placeId')

  mapOptions:  # ()->
    # console.log(@get('placeLocation'))
    # return {
    zoom: 8
    center: @get('placeLocation')
    # }
  # mapHeight: null
  # mapWidth: null
  map: null

  init: ()->
    console.log('init')
    @._super
    @set('mapContainer', @get('mapContainer')[0])
    @set('placesService',
      new google.maps.places.PlacesService(@get('mapContainer')))
    console.log(@get('mapOptions'))
    @set('map',
      new google.maps.Map(@get('mapContainer'), @get('mapOptions')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@get` must be executed within context of the instance.  Here you're executing it within the context of the window.

You could change your mapOptions to a computed property:

```
mapOptions:  function(){
    return {
      zoom: 8
      center: this.get('placeLocation')
    }
}.property('placeLocation')
```

Or if you just want it to be a method, you wouldn't use a `getter`, you would just call the func

```
mapOptions:  function(){
    return {
      zoom: 8
      center: this.get('placeLocation')
    }
}


@set('map', new google.maps.Map(@get('mapContainer'), @mapOptions()))
```

Comment: Could you explain why my @get call was in the context of the window as opposed to the context of the instance? Having trouble understanding why that is.

Comment: When it is building the inner hash it goes through and evaluates all of the values and assigns them to the keys.  While doing this, the scope is whatever your scope is outside of the hash.  You can see that here as well http://jsbin.com/xufexa/1/edit,  It isn't anything Ember related, just a scoping issue of javascript.